# do we need to call class for static methods?

Tags: java, oop

given a static method in a class, are there instances where we don't need to call "Class.method()" to run the method?

For example in the following code, is it allowed to just call `sleep()` without a reference to `Thread` (the class where the method comes from)?

```
public class ThreadNoJoin extends Thread {
   public void run() {
   for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   try {
      sleep((int) (Math.random() * 3000));    //this is the important line
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

I know `Thread.sleep()` will work, but I was curious why `sleep()` on its own works as well.

Comment: If you want to avoid writing class name you can use static import. So to use `sleep` instead of `Thread.sleep` add at import section `import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use sleep() without a reference to Thread in this context, because sleep() is a static method in the Thread class and the class you are using - ThreadNoJoin - extends Thread. When a class extends another class, it inherits all of its public and protected methods and can use them directly.

However, it's important to note that just because you can do this does not mean you should. Using Thread.sleep() is more readable and clearer than just using sleep(), because it makes it clear where the method is coming from.

You can use a feature called : static import, which allows you to import all static methods from a class. This way you could use the sleep() method without mentioning Thread every time. Please note that this approach should not be used often, because it can make the code more difficult to read if it's not clear where the method is coming from. When you see sleep() without any context, you may not immediately know it's a method from Thread. Therefore, the readability of the code may suffer, especially for people who are not familiar with the codebase.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, it's because `this.sleep()` (and `this` is *implicit*) **is** `Thread.sleep()` (because of inheritance). **But** it's also possible to `import static` methods.